# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()

Tags: java, spring

I have been getting this error very often in my code, and it is eating up most of my time.

Is there any way where I can get the information about what particular element is missing in the controller.

I also tried implementing [Spring MVC + Logback SLF4j example by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-logback-slf4j-example/) but it is not working and I am not getting the logs.

I have gone through all the answers on this topic but none of them discusses how we can avoid it.

Below are the steps that I am performing for logging as suggested by the tutorial.

1. Added dependency in pom.xml
2. created logback.xml in resources folder for logging level details.
3. Added below line in my controller class

--

```
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WelcomeController.class);
```

I am using Spring and Hibernate.